# C++ --- leading zeros in filenames (CSV-files) --- storing/splitting values of a std::vector

Tags: c++, csv, vector, fstream

I want to store the values of a `std::vector<T>` into a bunch of csv-files.

The values shall be split in a way that `N` (with `N < std::vector<T>.size()`) values are stored in one csv-file, except the last file, it can store between `1` and `N` values.

Assuming `std::vector<T>.size() == 113` and a `N == 10` results in

```
00.csv
01.csv
.
.
.
12.csv (with only 3 elements)
```

Is there an easy way out there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partitioning/batch/chunk a container into equal sized pieces using std algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226952/partitioning-batch-chunk-a-container-into-equal-sized-pieces-using-std-algorithm) - if not, partitioning would be the keyword.

Comment: Thanks but missing the leading zero filename creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the filename do `sprintf(fileName, "%02d.csv", fileNumber);`

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/